# Data from API is not showing in my UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4

I am trying to display data from an API into UITableView. The problem I am having is that I am not getting any of the data coming through into UITableView. Now I see that in my Data Source and Delegate are hooked up.
[image: Data Source and Delegate]
I also know that I am able to access to the API as I am able to print to the console.

There are no errors only that I am not able to see any data.  Below is the code that I have.

```
class StandingTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var standing = ""
let SEASON_URL = "https://ergast.com/api/f1"

var champions: [DriverStanding] = []
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.title = standing

    fetchJSON(standing: standing)

}
private func fetchJSON(standing: String){
    let JsonUrlString = SEASON_URL + "/" + String(standing) + "/driverstandings.json"
    print(JsonUrlString)
    guard let url = URL(string: JsonUrlString) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to get data from url:", err)
                return
            }

            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                // Swift 4.1
                decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                let firstDriver = try decoder.decode(F1Data.self, from: data)
                self.champions = firstDriver.mrData.standingsTable.standingsLists[0].driverStandings
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return champions.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cellId")

    let champion = champions[indexPath.row]
    let driverName = "\(champion.driver.givenName!) \(champion.driver.familyName!)"
    cell.textLabel?.text = driverName


    return cell
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I have checked that the "cellId" matches what I have in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `numberOfSections` return `1` or delete the entire method as the default value **is** 1

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 0
}
```

And reuse cells, set the subtitle style in Interface Builder and write

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)
```

Answer (score -1):

Any updates on this? Did removing the method :

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
// #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
return 0
}
```

work?

Comment: Pressed it by mistake